# What are your favorite LogParser Scripts?

Tags: iis, logging, scripting, logparser, iis-logs

What are you favorite LogParser 2.2 Scripts to run against IIS logs and Event logs?

I am putting a list of scripts together to run against our production environment to proactively look for issues and to help when isolating performance problems.

Do you have a certain list of LogParser 2.2 scripts that you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to run queries to identify the top pages requested, the pages that have the highest sum of "time taken" as well as the pages with the highest average "time taken".

With these it helps to identify heavy load sections, and sometimes leads to areas that can be improved with caching ETC.

Answer (score 0):

We usually yank the lot back into SQL server then query what we're after from there. I work for a shared hoster and one of the things we look for is excessive scripting errors in the IIS logs and ASP.NET exceptions logged to the event log. On shared box with 1200 sites these can bring it to it's knees if not kept in check, exceptions and errors are always expensive. We then use the data to let the culprits know their sites need fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Not a script per se, but I like to use LogParser against the Application Event Logs and look for top 10 application errors in there.